# Three-Handed Gambler’s Ruin - end of the game

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Three players start with $a,b$, and $c$ chips, respectively, and play the following game. At each stage, two players are picked at random, and one of those two is picked at random to give the other a chip. This continues until one of the three is out of chips, and quits the game; the other two continue until one player has all the chips.

Okay so let us consider the following stopping time: $T$- end of the game, the moment of time, when one of the players has all the chips.

How to show that $ET<\infty$? In other words: how do we know that game will end in some time?

Comment: Have you seen the proof for the two player game or that a random walk along a 1D line will hit zero with probability 1?  Either of these can be adapted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the result for the two-player game, it follows quickly.  From the point of view of player A, he face as coalition of B and C; he wants to get all their chips and he doesn't acre how they transfer chips among themselves.

This game almost surely ends in finite time.  Then either A has won, and then game is over, or B and C play as two-person game which again almost surely ends in finite time.

The result extends in the same way to the $n$-person game.

**EDIT**

For the two-person game, suppose there are $n$ chips in play, and let $E_k$ be the expected time till the end of the game if player A has $k$ chips.  We have the boundary conditions $$E_0=E_n=0$$ and the recurrence relation $$E_k=1+\frac12E_{k+1}+\frac12E_{k-1},\ k=1,2,\dots,n-1\tag1$$ because we always have to make one play, and A gains or loses a chip with equal probability.  $(1)$ is a second-order linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients, and may be solved by standard methods.  One can easily check that the solution is $$E_k=k(n-k),\ 0\leq k\leq n$$

One can extend this result to the three-person game by first computing the probability that the player with $k$ chips wins the two-person game in a manner similar to the way we computed the expectation of the length of the game.

Comment: Okay, but how to show it even for only two players?

Comment: I assumed you were acquainted with that.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Sheldon Ross, in "A simple solution to a multiple player gambler's ruin problem" [Amer. Math. Monthly 116 (2009), no. 1, 77–81], has studied this game for 3 or even more  players.  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00029890.2009.11920914?needAccess=true